# Is it possible to prevent tables from being split on pagebreak in flextable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, flextable

really enjoying flextable in combination with knitr and MS WORD here. I really only have this one issue left: I don't want my table to be split at the end of the page but rather the whole table be moved to the next page. Is there any way of doing this in flextable for MS Word?

Cheers

Comment: You can add a break page before your table with `body_add_break`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! While your answer is valid, it would seem more like a workaround though. I cannot simply add a pagebreak before every single table, that would look funky. The idea here is not to have to look at the word document and then insert pagebreaks before those tables that need it. Is there maybe a way to check whether a split in the table is imminent during the 'knitting' and only if the answer is yes insert the pagebreak?

Comment: Also I'm having trouble understanding how `body_add_break` and the other officer functions would work within Rmarkdown.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read enough carefully your question. as you are in Rmd, you can not use officer functions. I wrote `worded` (WIP) https://github.com/davidgohel/worded to provide some of these tools in Rmd. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Word (and so I don't know what code should be implemented to do so)

Comment: Thanks again for your replies and your packages, I will have a look at worded! In MS Word there is an option in table properties "Allow row to break across pages" that can be either set or not. This of course has to be 'unset' (0). The other one is in the paragraph properties, "Keep with next", this one has to be set (1). If both are set correctly, tables will not split upon pagebreak but are moved completely to the next page. Maybe that helps if you should be looking to implement this in the future.